# Relation between 3 database tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Im building a foosball game logging site, and need some advice on how to layout the database.
What I need help with is how to build the relations with these conditions in mind:

- Each game has 2 teams
- Each team has 1 or more users/players
- Since `team = colors`, each team can have different players in each game. In "game 1" players 1 & 2 can be in "team 1", but in "game 2" the "team 1" can consist of players 3 & 4.

This is the DB layout so far:

**Users/Players:**

- `id`
- `username`
- ...

**Teams/Colors:**

- `id`
- `name`
- ...

**Games:**

- `id`
- `team1_id`
- `team2_id`
- `team1_score`
- `team2_score`
- ...

Which additional table(s) do I need to add to make this work "the laravel way"?

Normally I would add a table with `game_id`, `user_id` and `team_id` columns, but I guess there is a cleaner solution with laravel.

Comment: Forget about the "Laravel way."  Use whatever naming convention you want for the ID columns.  You can specify the primary key in the model, e.g.: protected $primaryKey = 'team_id';.  You'll also need tables to hold the one-many relationship between a game and its players and a team and its players (e.g. a team might have 5 players but only 3 play in a particular game).

Comment: That's exactly what I need help with :) How would should i set up these tables? a one->many between games and players, and one between teams and players is not enough, since the same team will be used in  all matches but have different players in each game. I need some relation between a game, the teams and each teams players.